# Spring MVC 3 + Tiles 3

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles-3

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here. Basically I keep getting a 404 returned from my request into my Spring controller. The controller returns the view name "showcardOverview". The request makes it into the controller without a problem. I cannot figure out why Tiles cannot resolve the view name to the tile definition.

Below are my config files:

TILE DEFS

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base" template="/jsp/layouts/flagship.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="head" value="/jsp/assets/head.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="left" value="/jsp/assets/left.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="right" value="/jsp/assets/right.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="showcardOverview" extends="base">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/jsp/Showcard-Overview.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

SPRING VIEW CONFIG

```
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tms.zcore.movies.controller" />

<bean id="tilesviewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>      
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/conf/tiles/tiles-defs.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Edit:

Here is my Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/Showcard")
public class MovieShowcardController {

    @RequestMapping("/Overview/{id}/{seoName}")
    public String getMovieOverview(@PathVariable(value="id") String movieId, @PathVariable(value="seoName") String seoName, Model model) {
        return "showcardOverview";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the relative paths are correct: `/WEB-INF/conf/tiles/tiles-defs.xml` and `/jsp/Showcard-Overview.jsp` ?

Comment: Please show me a project directory if it's possbile. The reason may come from the path.

Comment: Hey. Yes the paths are correct. I've experimented by moving them in and out of the WEB-INF dir which always returns a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Have you debugged inside TilesViewResolver/TilesView to see if the Tiles definition gets resolved correctly? A 404 implies that it does and that Tiles has forwarded to the JSP but failed. Does the same work with Tiles 2? I.e. is this a Tiles 3 related issue?

Comment: I'm using the Spring TilesViewResolver & TilesView implementations so I cannot debug within them without the source. I have however swapped Tiles3 for the Tiles2 implementation and change my Spring config to match the changes. I'm still getting a 404 returned.

Comment: So, downloading and attaching the tiles source I can see that when I enter the BasicTilesContainer the Definition object which is passed into the render method has the following properties.  {name=showcardOverview, template=/WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/flagship.jsp, role=null, preparerInstance=null, attributes={body=/WEB-INF/jsp/Showcard-Overview.jsp, left=/WEB-INF/jsp/assets/left.jsp, head=/WEB-INF/jsp/assets/head.jsp, right=/WEB-INF/jsp/assets/right.jsp}}

Answer (score 1):

use full path of your jsp inside the tiles definition for example : instead of /jsp/layouts/flagship.jsp put /WEB-INF/jsp/layouts/flagship.jsp